# Access local dags folder from docker bash that runs in Window 10(20.04 LTS Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

1. I first installed the docker in my laptop(docker desktop) and then I run the docker using the Ubuntu 20.04 LST in windows 10.
2. later I exec the bash so that I could link the local dags folder to my docker dags folder.

bash code:

```
docker exec -ti 718257f95ec4 bash
```

Below is my current directory shown in the bash:

```
airflow@718257f95ec4:/opt/airflow$
```

I then try to use the below code to link my local Ubuntu 20.04 LTS windows 10 app to the dags but I could not properly find my local dags in my laptop.

Below is the code:

usually when I use only the ubuntu command it will be "/mnt/c/Users/username-name/Documents/dags" but after I access the bash, I do not know how to get into it.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v "This part I do not know how to access it":/dags  puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to copy your dag code from your host to your docker

`docker cp /yourlocalmachinepath/dagcode.py 718:/opt/airflow/dags`